# Calling Function in Original Scope of Object

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

Alright, given the following `Javascript` code that I DO NOT WANT to modify:

```
(function () {

    function iWantToCallThis(){
        // Do some stuff
    }

    window.SomeObject = {

        theirfunc = function(){
            // Do some stuff
        },

        otherFuncIDontWantToCall = function(){
            // This works, but don't want to call this function.
            iWantToCallThis();
            // does other stuff
        }

    }

}());
```

How can I access `iWantToCallThis()` through the scope of SomeObject like so:

```
window.SomeObject.theirfunc = (function (func){
    iWantToCallThis();
    func.apply(this, arguments);
} (win.SomeObject.theirfunc));
```

Even though I would consider that function to -technically- run in its original scope, I do not have access to `iWantToCallThis()`. Is there any way to access that function without editing the original source code?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. `iWantToCallThis` is local to your self-executing anonymous function. It's not a property.

Comment: IMHO, Douglas Crockford's "[Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)" is the definitive article on this topic. It should help persuade you that Private members are externally inaccessible except via Privileged methods.

Comment: Great article @Beetroot-Beetroot, mind posting that as an answer and I'll accept it? Definitely provides a better in-depth explanation of what I encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew,

IMHO, Douglas Crockford's "[Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)" is the definitive article on this topic.

It should help persuade you that Private members are externally inaccessible except via Privileged methods.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

The long answer is that if you change your mind about not changing the code, and then return `iWantToCallThis`, you may end up making a closure. If you do it a lot you might have performance issues.

Comment: I've already fixed it by modifying the third-party source code, but I didn't want to resort to that as I try to make all of my "hacks" not directly modify source. If someone updates the source with a new version, hack would just disappear instead of being in a separate file.

Comment: Good point. Is that third party software a known JS framework?

Comment: Yeah, it's HighCharts. So it will most likely be updated frequently.

Comment: If they wanted you to be able to call it, they would have made it a callable method. You could try submitting an enhancement request to them.

Answer (score 0):

no, because `iWantToCallThis` is neither returned from the IIFE nor is it stored in a public namespace/variable like SomeObject and theirfunc is.

If course, what you can do though, like you started to do in your second block, is to manually  reproduce the contents of that function and redeclare it. though that wouldn't be able to automatically grab the contents of the function due to its scope.

Comment: Sadly, I can't reproduce the contents, as the function changes other "non-scoped" variables :(

Comment: Oh well. thats your answer then :)